# Concurrently appending to list tail without a mutex lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, linked-list, atomic

I have a singly-linked list that is accessed concurrently by several threads.

The only operation that is in fact done concurrently is appending data to the tail of the list.
Right now, I use a mutex to ensure consistency. This is how the function looks like:

```
void AppendCommand(BackEndCommand * beCmd)
{
    Lock();

    if (cmdHead == nullptr)
    {
        beCmd->next = nullptr;
        cmdHead = beCmd;
        cmdTail = beCmd;
    }
    else
    {
        cmdTail->next = beCmd;
        cmdTail = beCmd;
    }

    ++numCommands;

    Unlock();
}
```

And the relevant list data and `BackEndCommand` type:

```
struct BackEndCommand {
    // Command number. Any of the BackEndCommandId.
    BackEndCommandId id;
    // Next on the command queue or null if end of list.
    struct BackEndCommand * next;
};

BackEndCommand * cmdHead = nullptr;
BackEndCommand * cmdTail = nullptr;
uint32_t numCommands = 0;
```

Now I'm curious if it would be possible in my case to replace that mutex lock by some sort of lock-less/atomic operations, maybe using the new C++11 [*atomics*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) library or similar?

Comment: Are there really no other operations, which are used concurrently?

Comment: No, just this one. Once the threads are done with the list, it is forwarded to a private thread that will process the commands serially.

Comment: The classic Michael-Scott lockless queue is a mpmc fifo data structure that maintains a head and a tail pointer; there's an improved version by [Fober, Orlarey and Letz](http://www.grame.fr/ressources/publications/LockFree.pdf). The tricky part is maintaining the read end pointer. If you didn't want to dequeue any elements and only enqueue, it'd be much simpler (e.g. if you had a single consumer that could steal the entire queue away).

Comment: Yes, that is actually the case, @Kerrek. Once the tasks are done with the list/queue, it is processed serially. Thanks!

Comment: @glampert: In that case, you should consider if you can even get away with spsc: You can give every thread its own, private queue, and the consumer thread goes around and steals all the thread-local queues. Then you have a compare-exchange at the enqueue, and a simple exchange at the stealing end.

Comment: Yes, very true @KerrekSB. An option I haven't considered! I might give it a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers showed how it can be done by adding elements at the beginning of the list. It is also possible to add elements at the end of the list. Note: In the following code, `_tail_hint` does not point always to the last element, but to an element near to the tail.

I also simplified the `if` condition by adding a *dummy* element.

```
struct list
{
    struct node
    {
        int _id;
        std::atomic<node*> _next;
        explicit node(int id, node* next)
            : _id{id}, _next{next}
        { }
    };
    node _head{0, nullptr};
    std::atomic<node*> _tail_hint{&_head};
    void append(node* n)
    {
        node* tail = _tail_hint;
        node* expected = nullptr;
        while (!tail->_next.compare_exchange_weak(expected, n)) {
            if (expected) {
                tail = expected;
                expected = nullptr;
            }
        }
        _tail_hint = n;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is quite possible, as long as the list is add-only (at least, during the period of concurrent access).

It's easiest if you don't mind your list in reverse order, because then there's only one variable to update (the tail), and you don't have to do as many atomic loads when traversing it.

I've adapted some working code from a project of mine (thoroughly unit tested). It implements an add-only LIFO linked list. (Note that I've renamed your `next` to `prev` for clarity.)

```
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<BackEndCommand*> tail(nullptr);

// Thread-safe
void add(BackEndCommand* element)
{
    assert(element != nullptr);

    auto prevTail = tail.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    do {
        element->prev = prevTail;
    } while (!tail.compare_exchange_weak(prevTail, element, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed));
}

// Thread-safe
void iterate()
{
    for (auto ptr = tail.load(std::memory_order_acquire); ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->prev) {
        // Do something with ptr
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how certain are you that the used memory orders are correct, in the add() function? I can't find any "standard / commonly accepted" code like this elsewhere on the net :/. But for some reason I do not feel that the memory orders here are the theoretically correct ones? :/

Comment: @Carlo I am 100% certain that the memory orders here are correct. What leads you to feel they aren't?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, but I wanted first to get to the bottom of this. I now verified that you are correct with the (especially for me fixed genmc, so it could handle this case; hence the delay). See my own answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57029910/what-are-the-correct-memory-orders-to-use-when-inserting-a-node-at-the-beginning/57211987#57211987

Comment: @Carlo Cool. You may also be interested in Relacy, which I've put to good use in tests for my own lock free data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

Here is example code from
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

You can even run it on the web page

```
#include <atomic>
template<typename T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node* next;
    node(const T& data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}
};

template<typename T>
class stack
{
    std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
 public:
    void push(const T& data)
    {
        node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);

//      // put the current value of head into new_node->next
//      new_node->next = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
//
//      // now make new_node the new head, but if the head
//      // is no longer what's stored in new_node->next
//      // (some other thread must have inserted a node just now)
//      // then put that new head into new_node->next and try again
//      while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node,
//                                        std::memory_order_release,
//                                        std::memory_order_relaxed))
//          ; // the body of the loop is empty
//
// Note: the above use is not thread-safe in at least 
// GCC prior to 4.8.3 (bug 60272), clang (bug 18899), MSVC (bug 819819).
// The following is a workaround:
        node<T>* old_head = head.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        do {
            new_node->next = old_head;
        } while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, new_node,
                                            std::memory_order_release,
                                            std::memory_order_relaxed));
    }
};
int main()
{
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to use either `atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` or `atomic_compare_exchange_strong()` to swap the `next` pointer of the previous tail with a pointer to your new element. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Setup your new element, setting its `next` pointer to zero. It is important that this is done before the `atomic<>` magic is invoked.
2. Determine the last element in the list. Use whatever method you like. Ensure that its `next` pointer is a `nullptr`. Lets call this `oldTail`.
3. Do the `atomic_compare_exchange_xxx()`, specifying that you expect the `oldTail->next` to still be a `nullptr`. This may fail. If it does, some other process has appended an element to the list while you were not looking. In that case, you need to go back to 2 to determine the new tail.
4. If the `atomic_compare_exchange_xxx()` succeeds, you are done.

This method requires the list end to be append only. It also requires the list elements to remain valid as long as another thread might hold a pointer to it in order to append another element. Ensuring this is tricky, especially if you try to do it in a lockless fashion, but it is possible (it can be achieved by the RCU pattern, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update).

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of the read-copy-update pattern. If got this right, this algorithm you describe is the one in @nosid's reply, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the same algorithm. However, I would actually try to find the end of the list first before trying to add the node, i. e. do a loop `while(node* nextNode = tail->next) tail = nextNode;`, both before the compare_exchange and after it failed. Both variants are equivalent in function, but there could be slight performance differences. I'm not sure, though, which one would actually run faster if there are performance differences.