# What are the correct memory orders to use when inserting a node at the beginning of a lock free singly linked list?

Tags: c++, c++17, lock-free, memory-barriers, stdatomic

I have a simple linked list. There is no danger of the ABA problem, I'm happy with Blocking category and I don't care if my list is FIFO, LIFO or randomized. At long as the inserting succeeds without making others fails.

The code for that looks something like this:

```
class Class {
  std::atomic<Node*> m_list;
  ...
};

void Class::add(Node* node)
{
  node->next = m_list.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  while (!m_list.compare_exchange_weak(node->next, node, std::memory_order_acq_rel, std::memory_order_acquire));
}
```

where I more or less randomly filled in the used memory_order's.
What are the right memory orders to use here?

I've seen people use `std::memory_order_relaxed` in all places, one guy on SO used that too, but then `std::memory_order_release` for the success case of compare_exchange_weak -- and the genmc project uses memory_order_acquire / twice memory_order_acq_rel in a comparable situation, but I can't get genmc to work for a test case :(.

Comment: @nicol Bolas I wish I could send a private message, but that doesn't seem possible. Doesn't c++17 imply c++? I pondered using c++11 as tag, but then read that the description of that tag is "not using anything later than C++11". So a tag like C++xy seems to mean "How can I do this using C++xy or earlier".

Comment: "*Doesn't c++17 imply c++?*" In a normal sense, yes. But if someone is looking at questions in the [tag:c++], they won't see questions tagged only with [tag:c++17]. It's silly, but that's how the system works. And people frequently look at specific tags to find questions in their topics of expertise.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok-- I guess you're right. From the view point of people looking for tag 'C++14' means "I have knowledge up to and including the standard of C++14", hence it means "1990 - 2014". While (as per the description of the tags themselves) a person tagging a question with C++14 means "This MAY involve C++ code that uses techniques up to C++14, but not beyond", as they are not certain they will use the highest value that is acceptable to them. From this we can conclude that someone looking for C++11 should also get to see the C++14 tagged question, which isn't the case. I think that

Comment: the best solution is to add all tags from "might be sufficient" to "may be used at most" rather than [C++] and "may be used at most" though. Aka, in this case the question should have been tagged with [C++11], [C++14] and [C++17]. That way anyone with the knowledge required (C++11 and up) would see it, but warning people not to use tricks from C++20. Someone who ONLY wants to see [C++] and not [C++11] would not be bothered with it then.

Comment: The tag system is to help people find questions they're interesting in seeing; it can only do so much.  If you had for example a hard limit of C++14 but not C++17 features, that would be something to mention in the text of the question, as well as tags.  With C++20 not being finalized yet, it's already the default assumption that you can only use at most C++17.

Comment: Can you link the examples you've seen of `mo_relaxed`?  `mo_relaxed` while the new node is still private makes perfect sense (but even better would be calling constructors to not even require atomicity while writing a non-shared object), with `mo_release` for the store that "publishes" them to other threads.

Comment: @PeterCordes I saw that while searching with https://searchcode.com/?q=while+%28%21compare_exchange_weak&src=3&src=2&lan=15&lan=16

Comment: I’m pretty sure that since you’re not reading the value from the node, a relaxed load is fine when grabbing the head. When publishing via the CAS you want to use release so that any readers acquire the correct value stored in the node (this is a speculative assumption since you haven’t included code that does this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the *excellent* tool from Michalis Kokologiannakis [genmc](https://github.com/MPI-SWS/genmc), I was able to verify the required memory orders with the following test code. Unfortunately, genmc currently requires C code, but that doesn't matter for figuring out what the memory orders need to be of course.

```
// Install https://github.com/MPI-SWS/genmc
//
// Then test with:
//
// genmc -unroll 5 -- genmc_sll_test.c

// These header files are replaced by genmc (see /usr/local/include/genmc):
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRODUCER_THREADS 3
#define CONSUMER_THREADS 2

struct Node
{
  struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* const deleted = (struct Node*)0xd31373d;

_Atomic(struct Node*) list;

void* producer_thread(void* node_)
{
  struct Node* node = (struct Node*)node_;

  // Insert node at beginning of the list.
  node->next = atomic_load_explicit(&list, memory_order_relaxed);
  while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak_explicit(&list, &node->next,
             node, memory_order_release, memory_order_relaxed))
    ;

  return NULL;
}

void* consumer_thread(void* param)
{
  // Replace the whole list with an empty list.
  struct Node* head = atomic_exchange_explicit(&list, NULL, memory_order_acquire);
  // Delete each node that was in the list.
  while (head)
  {
    struct Node* orphan = head;
    head = orphan->next;
    // Mark the node as deleted.
    assert(orphan->next != deleted);
    orphan->next = deleted;
  }

  return NULL;
}

pthread_t t[PRODUCER_THREADS + CONSUMER_THREADS];
struct Node n[PRODUCER_THREADS]; // Initially filled with zeroes -->
                                 // none of the Node's is marked as deleted.

int main()
{
  // Start PRODUCER_THREADS threads that each append one node to the queue.
  for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREADS; ++i)
    if (pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, producer_thread, &n[i]))
      abort();

  // Start CONSUMER_THREAD threads that each delete all nodes that were added so far.
  for (int i = 0; i < CONSUMER_THREADS; ++i)
    if (pthread_create(&t[PRODUCER_THREADS + i], NULL, consumer_thread, NULL))
      abort();

  // Wait till all threads finished.
  for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREADS + CONSUMER_THREADS; ++i)
    if (pthread_join(t[i], NULL))
      abort();

  // Count number of elements still in the list.
  struct Node* l = list;
  int count = 0;
  while (l)
  {
    ++count;
    l = l->next;
  }

  // Count the number of deleted elements.
  int del_count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREADS; ++i)
    if (n[i].next == deleted)
      ++del_count;

  assert(count + del_count == PRODUCER_THREADS);
  //printf("count = %d; deleted = %d\n", count, del_count);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of which is

> $ genmc -unroll 5 -- genmc_sll_test.c
>   Number of complete executions explored: 6384
>   Total wall-clock time: 1.26s

Replacing either the `memory_order_release` or `memory_order_acquire` with `memory_order_relaxed` causes an assertion.

In fact, it can be checked that using exclusive `memory_order_relaxed` when just inserting nodes is sufficient to get them all cleanly in the list (although in a 'random' order - there is nothing sequential consistent, so the order in which they are added is not necessarily the same as that the threads try to add them, if such correlation exists for other reasons).

However, the `memory_order_release` is required so that when `head` is read with `memory_order_acquire` we can be certain that all non-atomic `next` pointers are visible in the "consumer" thread.

Note there is no ABA problem here because values used for `head` and `next` cannot be "reused" before they are deleted by the 'consumer_thread' function, which is the only place where these node are allowed to be deleted (therefore), implying that there can only be one consumer thread (this test code does NOT check for the ABA problem, so it also works using 2 CONSUMER_THREADS).

The actual code is a garbage collection mechanism where multiple "producer" threads add pointers to a singly linked list when those can be deleted, but where it is only safe to actually do so in one specific thread (in that case there is only one "consumer" thread thus, which performs this garbage collection at a well-known place in a main-loop).